# Does "No more nails" grip strongly enough to hold soffit vents in place while it is setting?

Tags: glue

I need to fix some soffit vents to a UPVC soffit, due do the fitness of the UPVC soffit the vents tend to fall out.  Will “No more nails” grip strongly enough to keep them in place until it sets?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the "No More Nails" glue you have is anything like the stuff we have in my part of the world but if it is you should have no problems. However, our stuff goes off pretty quick and you would need the vent in place within a minute or so, otherwise a skin will form on the glue.

You also have a couple of options for holding the vents in place while the glue sets.

- Use tape to hold the vent in place. It really won't take much to hold it there.
- Push a thin pin or very thin nail through the vent in such a way that it will poke trough into or immediately above the surface you're attaching the vent to, depending on what material that is.

Answer (score 6):

Both Liquid Nails and PL make fast set urethane adhesives in a caulking tube. I have used them for various repairs and setting crown moldings. They will hold a fair amount of weight after only 5 to 10 seconds of contact, so I'm sure they would work for your vents.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought so. I'd let the glue go "off" for a few minutes before inserting the soffits (but don't wait too long).

From the picture the vents look quite light.

Comment: The vents are light, however I have a lot to fix in.  Due to using a ladder, I will not be able to do more then a few at a time if I have to wait for a few minutes.

Comment: @Walker - but as you'll need to move the ladder you could apply the glue on the ground, move the ladder and then carry the vents up to fix. Though that could get messy. Hmm.